# Суффиксы -ЕВЛ-/-ИВЛ- в прилагательных

Tags: суффиксы, суффиксы-прилагательных

Скажите, пожалуйста, как объяснить человеку, что в слове "неодушевлённый" суффикс -евл-, а не -ивл-? Ведь есть же, например, слова "умилостивлённый", "сфальшивленный"... По какому принципу идёт это чередование? После шипящей, без ударения? Или есть ещё какое-то правило? У Розенталя не нашла.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что никак. Суффикс "евл" является уникальным, как и суффикс "ёл" (тяжелый), потому слово просто запоминаем. Что касается других примеров: на мой взгляд, дело в имеющихся в языке родственных прилагательных.

---

Вы наверняка знаете, что суффикс **"ив"** является ударным, а **"ев"**- безударным,  однако на это правило есть два исключения: *юродивый и милостивый*. Думаю, вы поняли, почему я про **милостивый** написал.

---

А насчет "сфальшивленный" все и так понятно: суффикс **"ивл"** ударный, в родственном прилагательном "фальшивый" суффикс **"ив"** тоже ударный.

---

Согласно этой логике, мы и должны писать слово "неодушевленный" с суффиксом **"евл"** (т.к. не исключение, суффикс безударный).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Всё-таки нужно запомнить или можно объяснить безударной позицией? 
Про "умилостивлённый"  всё поняла)

Comment: Тут ведь нужно понимать, с чем мы работаем: с орфографией или морфемикой? Если с орфографией, то можно объяснить безударной позицией, если с морфемикой, то нужно запоминать суффикс.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Теперь всё понятно!